# M1 Changing website to https breaks product pages

Tags: magento-1.9, products, https, product-urls

Currently our website is only secured on checkout. We want the whole site to be secured so we had our IT guy do that. The whole site is secured EXCEPT I cant get to the individual product pages. It breaks.

Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the Base URL of your webshop to **https** protocol

```
https://yourdomain.com
```

Make sure to change also the value of **Use Secure URLs in Frontend** and **Use Secure URLs in Admin** options to **Yes**.

Then Save Config.
Then Clear cache and everything will be good.